# Simple show/hide gone wrong in Javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I'm trying to create a show/hide function for data within a table populated with data from a mssql database. The function should look for rows with the same value in the "capability" column and onclick, hide all rows with the same value. After this, a row is inserted into the table with the same capability value, but summarizes the data in the hidden rows. This should work in the way that grouping cells together works in excel.

**I've managed to get this to work, but it only works for the first click and I receive a "cannot read innerHTML property of NULL" for any of the function's calls after that.**

```
function compactRows(thisrow) {
  var totalRows = document.getElementById("DataTable").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

  var summaryVal1= [];
  var summaryVal2= [];

  for(var i = 1; i < totalRows;i++) {
    var trID = "capability" + i;
    if(thisrow.innerHTML == document.getElementById(trID).innerHTML) { //The error gets returned on this line
        summaryVal1.push(document.getElementById(trID).parentNode.children[5].innerHTML);
        summaryVal2.push(document.getElementById(trID).parentNode.children[14].innerHTML);
        document.getElementById(trID).parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  createNewRow(thisrow, summaryVal1, summaryVal2);
}

//I took out the logic for the data summarizing in the createNewRow function because I don't think its relevant to the issue I'm having. Also, I didn't want to crowd the area with unrelated code
function createNewRow(row, ibxMobile, overallStatus) {
var table = document.getElementById("DataTable");
var localRow = table.insertRow(row.parentNode.rowIndex);

var cell1 = localRow.insertCell(0);
cell1.setAttribute("id", "entry1");

var cell2 = localRow.insertCell(0);
cell2.setAttribute("id", "Capability");
cell2.innerHTML = row.innerHTML;

var cell3 = localRow.insertCell(0);
cell3.setAttribute("id", "entry3");
}
```

The function called at the bottom, createNewRow, handles making the row to be entered after all the rows are hidden. It also, handles the logic for summarizing the hidden rows.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

**Edit 1: example table set up**

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Entry1 </th>
<th>Capability</th>
<th>Entry3 </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1.1</td>
<td id="Capability1" onclick="compactRows(this)">Lasers</td>
<td>stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1.2</td>
<td id="Capability2" onclick="compactRows(this)">Lasers</td>
<td>things</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2.1</td>
<td id="Capability3" onclick="compactRows(this)">Beams</td>
<td>more things</td>
</tr>
</table>

//The Below table is what it looks like after clicking either of the first two entries

<table>
<tr>
<th>Entry1 </th>
<th>Capability</th>
<th>Entry3 </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td id="Capability">Lasers</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2.1</td>
<td id="Capability3" onclick="compactRows(this)">Beams</td>
<td>more things</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where do you initialize `thisrow` ?

Comment: Need more of your code to see what is going on here...

Comment: So, if you have three rows in your DataTable, are you sure you have three elements with ids of `capability1`, `capability2`, and `capability3`?

Comment: How 'bout some markup? :P

Comment: Also, your loop only iterates over two elements, FYI. I think you probably meant it to loop the same number of times as there are rows in your DataTable.

Comment: @Brett, if I throw an alert into the for loop, I am getting a message for every row in the table, so I'm confident thats fine. Additionally, if I inspect my table, all the elements are coming through properly with ids, capability1, capability2, etc.

Comment: In the table example, can you include a row after CreateNewRow function has been called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Capability1" id for any rows after the "CreateNewRow" is called. Therefore, the second time "CompactRows()" is called a null reference is thrown when accessing "document.getElementById("**Capability1**").innerHTML".  Rework the CreateNewRow to inlcude the increment for the Capability id value or test that "getElementById" actually returns an object before attempting to access the innerHTML method.